# Using Selenium to scrape email addresses by checking for characters

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape email addresses off of Facebook business info pages such as the following:
[Facebook Business Page Example](https://www.facebook.com/alliancejjsandiego/info/?tab=page_info)

But was having some trouble correctly determining the XPath to do so. I later learned that Facebook doesn't have a consistent xpath for its business info page.  The XPath varies from business to business meaning that my current idea of using XPath won't work.

[image]

After some html inspection however I did learn that on the facebook business info page, if an email is present on the page, it'll be the only piece of content within a div that has the "@" symbol.  So my next throught was, "what if i could determine if the @ symbol was present in the html? and if it was, maybe I could pull the content from that".  So that's kind of where I stand right now. I'm trying to first determine if the email is present on the page through the "@" symbol and if it is present, I want to scrape the content that is using the "@" symbol.

I looked into the following methods to do so:

```
email = driver.getPageSource().contains("@")
```

In order to return a boolean value as to whether or not the @ symbol was present on the page but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not just use Facebook's GraphQL instead? It includes [an `emails` field for Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page).

Comment: I should have done that from the start but now that I've developed most of the other features already, I feel I might as well just finish what I started

Comment: The Facebook TOS specifically prohibits scraping; they'll happily finish your access for you when caught.

Comment: I'm aware, it'll only be for a limited amount of time.

Comment: Pity. All you need is to [register for an access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens), then use a GET to `http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<page_id>?fields=emails` to get your emails listed for one page, or use `http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/?ids=<page1_id>,<page2_id>,<page_3_id>&fields=emails` to get the same info for multiple pages at once. It is *so easy*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't scrape. Just use the GraphQL API. This isn't hard at all, install the [`facebook-sdk` package](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) from GitHub with `pip`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.git
```

Then [register and configure your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register) to obtain an app ID and secret, then run the following code:

```
from facebook import GraphAPI

APP_ID = '<your_app_id>'
APP_SECRET = '<your_app_secret>'

graph = GraphAPI(version=2.5)
graph.access_token = graph.get_app_access_token(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)

# sequence of page ids you want to retrieve emails for
pages = ('page1_id', 'page2_id', 'page3_id')

objects = graph.get_objects(pages, fields='name,emails')

for page in objects.values():
    print('{}: {}'.format(page['name'], ', '.join(page['emails'])))
```

This can be done *next to your Selenium app* without further retooling.

Demo for your sample page:

```
>>> pages = ('alliancejjsandiego',)
>>> objects = graph.get_objects(pages, fields='emails,name')
>>> for page in objects.values():
...     print('{}: {}'.format(page['name'], ', '.join(page['emails'])))
...
Alliance Jiu-Jitsu San Diego: info@alliancesandiego.com
```

Comment: Does this work for searching `Real estate in New York` and navigating all the listed Facebook groups to find email addresses listed in Groups?

Comment: @AtomStore: please reference the API documentation for what is available and what isn't. I see that [pages can be searched for](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching) (and you can [specify business locations like New York using the `location` field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching#fields)), and the page type [includes `emails` as an attribute, which is a list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/).